# Best approach to have client notified to database changes

Tags: sql, asp.net, azure, xamarin, azure-sql-database

I have been researching and read over many different threads both here and on the Xamarin forums but I have been having a hard time grasping the concept which I'm looking for. I feel like all of the information on event messaging is very vague in the sense that I cannot find anything in a similar use case as mine, which surprised me as my scenario is a pretty common one I believe, and I think I just need to be pointed in the right direction and get a better understanding of what exactly I need.

What i'm looking for is the best approach for my app to efficiently listen for database updates while running. In my specific use case, a user sends a connection, much like that of Linkedin, to another user on the app. I'm assuming the listening is the same type of approach you would use when listening for messages in something like a chat app.

I'm using an SQL Server and an ASP.NET backend, and from my understanding, SQL is not a real-time database like Firebase so I cannot hook directly into it to listen for changes.

From my research, I have found that what I probably need is a messaging service or event service. [https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/services/event-hubs/](http://Azure%20Events%20Hub) is what seems like what I need but I was just confused in the nature of the service, and if it's well suited for what I need. I'm also assuming that the typical use case would be that I send an event when a change is made to the database via a call to my web api.

Again, I am just looking for some pointers in the right direction.
Thanks!

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/data-cloud/azure-services/azure-signalr

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using SQL Database (at this moment), there's no way for you to subscribe on events. Using Azure Cosmos DB, you can use the change feed + Azure Functions to get those changes.

[image]

What you can do is add a message to a queue, whenever something changes in your database. Then, you can have Azure Functions to be triggered by that message.

PS: You can use Event Hubs + Azure Functions too.

Comment: Thank you for the response. In theory, could I just use Event Hubs and trigger an event in my web API without having to migrate to the Azure Cosmos db? I'm not sure if that's what you meant in your last line. Thanks!

Comment: it depends on your scenario, but basically what you need is some event based approach.  You can use any of the solutions I gave...